# Microsoft Access 2013 Input Mask

Tags: ms-access, input-mask

How do I place on a input mask on an entity on my table?

I want the entity LibraryID's mask to consist of 2 uppercase letters followed by 4 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this format on your field input mask:

[[image]